# Curl request not work in live server

Tags: php, curl

I'm using this function for get data from web service

```
function get_on_going_vehicle_number($vehicle_category) {

    $xml_data = '<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://schemas.asdasdasd.com/xsdabcdf/v1">

 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 <v1:vehicleCategory>' . $vehicle_category . '</v1:vehicleCategory>
 </v1:GetOnGoingVehicleNo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';



    $URL = "http://api.somegate.vfg.lk:8580/Getsomething/1.0";

    $ch = curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: text/xml',
        'Authorization: Bearer 7655a410-d019-3f09-b214-08c40e737af0'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

after executing this in localhost it works perfect and not in my live server.

when I includ this

```
if (curl_exec($curl) === FALSE) {
   die("Curl Failed: " . curl_error($curl));
} else {
   return curl_exec($curl);
}
```

it says `could not connect to host`

so please tell me the reason for this. Thanks

Comment: host could be blocking, ask them

Comment: Either the hostname or port is wrong, or there's a firewall blocking it.

Comment: @Barmar in my localhost it works fine and one of my server

Comment: If it's failing on a hosting service, they may have a firewall blocking it.[

Comment: give init directly.

$URL = curl_init("http://api.somegate.vfg.lk:8580/Getsomething/1.0");

other chances are your url can be wrong or restrictions like firewall etc.

Comment: @syam.k gave it directly and not working.

Comment: Then, check the connectivity towards that api.

Comment: @syam.k how can i check the connection

Comment: You can do a telnet to ip and port to check connectivity. You can just call file_get_contents  $response = file_get_contents("http://api.somegate.vfg.lk:8580/Getsomething/1.0");     If the endpoint returns an HTTP error status (e.g. 401), the file_get_contents function fails with a warning and returns null. If the body contains an error message, you cannot retrieve it. Use the below link for curl help. 
                         http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @syam.k It returns nothing :(

Comment: add `curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>fopen("php://output","wb")));`   and post the VERBOSE log..